# mathematical issue while encrypting/ decrypting in CRT.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

I have a plaintext to be decrypted as follows:

$m = 2^{953} \bmod 1147$.

However, when I type $2^{953}$ in the calculator it gives me a math error!

So, how can I solve this equation? Even though, I couldn't find an answer for this on the Internet.

The answer should be $721$.

Comment: Try [Exponentiation by Squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)  Or, easier in this case, factor $1147$ and solve the problem for each of the factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One very fast way for a computer to do this is to use Fast Modular Exponentiation (FME). Python has a built-in function named "pow" to do this (thanks to kelalaka for this!), where

```
pow(A, B, mod=C)
```

solves the problem $A^B \mod C$. You can also find websites which do FME like https://www.dcode.fr/modular-exponentiation for example. Both my code and that website's code were able to find the answer just a second or two. The math behind FME is based on the nice property of Modular Arithmetic that
$$xy \text{ mod } z = (x \text{ mod } z)(y \text{ mod }z).$$
Specifically, the way that my code works is that it splits 953 into the sum of powers of 2, i.e.
$$953 = 2^9 + 2^8 + 2^7 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^0,$$
so then
$$ 2^{953} = 2^{2^9 + 2^8 + 2^7 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^0} $$
which is
$$ 2^{953} = 2^{2^0} \cdot 2^{2^3} \cdot 2^{2^4} \cdot 2^{2^5} \cdot 2^{2^7} \cdot 2^{2^8} \cdot 2^{2^9}. $$
For a human this doesn't look easy but for a computer it is efficient since $(a^{2^b})^2) = a^{2^{b+1}}$, so the computer can just remember the last thing it computed and just square it. Hope this helps!

Comment: If my explanation isn't clear, then Khan Academy and Wikipedia have good articles on this: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation & https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: You basically reinvent the python [pow function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). Notice the third parameter. Also, the algorithm has a name [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: Didn't know about the built-in function; thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I don't think that FME and Exponentiation by Squaring are quite the same thing; they draw upon the same idea but looking through the Wikipedia article, Exponentiation by Squaring produces the ordinary exponent (not the modular one). The reason I included my answer despite your comment on the original question was that it's significantly more efficient to use FME than to calculate the ordinary exponent using Exponentiation by Squaring and then consider the modulus afterwards.

Comment: Well, One can easily modify any step-by-step exponentiation algorithm into a modular version. Maybe I just needed to link this page instead of the other. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation